# Arduino and STM8 I2C Communication

Tags: arduino, i2c, stm8

I want to I2C communication stm8s(slave) and arduino uno(master), but it does not work.

Arduino Uno(master) code:

```
void setup() {
  Wire.begin(); // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
}

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x30); // transmit to device #0x30
  Wire.write(0x15);              // sends one byte
  Wire.endTransmission();    // stop transmitting

  delay(500);
}
```

STM8 Slave Code with peripheral library: main.c

```
CLK_HSIPrescalerConfig(CLK_PRESCALER_HSIDIV1);

I2C_DeInit();
I2C_Init(100000, SLAVE_ADDRESS, I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2, I2C_ACK_CURR, I2C_ADDMODE_7BIT, 16);

char veri_bas[1];

while (1)
{

I2C_GenerateSTART(ENABLE);

/* Disable Acknowledgement */
I2C_AcknowledgeConfig(I2C_ACK_NEXT);

/* Send STOP Condition */
I2C_GenerateSTOP(ENABLE);


uint8_t gelen = I2C_ReceiveData();
//uint8_t gelen = 0x15;
sprintf(veri_bas ,"%d" ,gelen);
sendstring(veri_bas);
}
```

STM8 - main.h:

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H
#define __MAIN_H

#define I2C_SPEED 100000
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS  0x30

#endif /* __MAIN_H */
```

Arduino sends data, i saw it on the ossiloscope. Pinout(SCL-SDA-GND) and I2C resistors are correct. Sendstring function is correct. But it does not work. Thank you!

Comment: Why is your STM8 *slave* code generating starts & stops?!? That's the *master's* job.

Answer (score 2):

Your slave should not generate START and STOP events.  It must wait for and respond to them appropriately.